# How can I design a mechanism to know if a job has been done when using Kafka between microservices?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, system-design

I'm working with a workflow with several components which need to consume records from a Kafka topic and produce to another topic. It looks like, ComponentA produces records to TopicA. Then ComponentB consumes records from TopicA, does some processing, and produces records to TopicB. Then components C, D...

My question is how could I know on ComponentA(or on whatever component) if the job has been done through ComponentA to ComponentD?

For now, I'm monitoring lags of every topic and choose to manually acknowledge to the Kafka broker when consuming records from the Kafka topic so that I can precisely know if a record has been processed or not. But this brings me a lot of troubles to handle and it will bring me more if I want to run two jobs in parallel. Is there any better or alternative solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the Saga, or other choreography patterns.

You could use workflow tools like Airflow.

At a high level, you'll need some central database that tracks which steps are being taken at any time. Give each event some ID; store which component is processing those events as it sees it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! From my understanding, I need to use a central database to store the ids of every record I send to every topic, and mark each row as done after the component finish processing the record. Doesn't this make every component rely on the central database while we want to decouple the system by using a message queue like Kafka?

Comment: Kafka is decoupled. You could have producers implemented in different languages from consumers. They don't know about each other. If you want to track the events, that's not coupled to Kafka clients, but rather external observers to your system